# How to do parse json array dynamically in shell script using jq too in shell script

Tags: jq

Suppose I have the following json in a file json.txt

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "things_carried": [
    "apples",
    "hat",
    "harmonica"
  ],
  "children": [
    {
      "first_name": "Bobby Sue",
      "last_name": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first_name": "John Jr",
      "last_name": "Smith"
    }
  ]
}
```

In shell script I had written the logic to find the size of children array using jq tool .

```
size=cat json.txt | jq '.children | length'    
i=0

while [ $i -le $size ]    
do
    array[$i]=$(cat json.txt | jq '.children[$i]')
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

On running this it gives the following error -

```
.children[$i]          1 compile error
```

It seems that it is not able to replace the variable i in the children[] array , as because if we give the expression -

```
array[$i]=$(cat json.txt | jq '.children[0]')
```

it runs well .

Can someone help me .

Comment: `size=cat json.txt | jq '.children | length' ` will not do what you want. You need to use *command substitution*

Comment: size=cat json.txt | jq '.children | length,it will give the length of children array . Now through a loop I want to assign each json object inside the children[] array to another array variable

Comment: Please check `echo $size` to see

Comment: $size is giving correct value = 2 . The problem lies in the jq tool . If we give shell variable inside the jq tool , jq fails to parse .

Answer (score 2):

You're using single quotes around the jq program. Shells do not interpolate variables inside single quotes; this is intentional and the jq manual recommends using single quotes around programs for this reason.

An argument syntax is provided by jq for this purpose. This syntax allows you to set jq variables to the value of shell variables. You could replace your current jq invocation with this:

`array[$i]=$(cat json.txt | jq --arg i $i '.children[$i | tonumber]')`

Comment: `--arg` would make jq interpret the value of $i as a string. One should use `--argjson` flag instead for the value of $i to be read

Comment: Agreed! In the code above, I use `tonumber` to work around that. I'm pretty sure that jq 1.5 hadn't been released yet, hence why I didn't used `--argjson`.

Comment: Oh I actually missed the `tonumber` and yeah I figured that jq 1.5 wasn't probably out then :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just trying to set the children to a bash array variable.

You don't need to loop, just set the array directly.

```
$ IFS=$'\n'; array=($(jq -c '.children[]' json.txt))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the following syntax:

```
array[$i]=$(cat json.txt | jq '.children['${i}']')
```